# How to use labels inserted in .dtx files?

Tags: auctex, reftex-mode

I wonder if there is a way to have `reftex` print and use labels inserted in a `.dtx` file from the TOC menu.

As every line in a `.dtx` file begins with `%`, `reftex` seems unable to display labels.  For example, from the TOC menu (`C-c =`), hitting on `l` has no effect.

Furthermore, as `reftex` does not see the labels, I am unable to insert references from `C-c )`.

On another side, `Ref -> Global Actions -> Goto Label` works as expected.

I use emacs 26.1, and AUCTeX 13.0.14 from gnu.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RefTeX sees the `\label` macros which are commented out, it just doesn't show them by default.  You can access them in the `*RefTeX Select*` buffer.  This is a documented feature.  From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex.html#SEC13):

> ### 3.2 Referencing Labels
>
> RefTeX scans the document in order to find all labels. [...].
> Here is a list of special commands in the
> selection buffer. A summary of this information is always available
> from the selection process by pressing <kbd>?</kbd>.
>
> #### Controlling what gets displayed
>
> [...]
> <kbd>%</kbd> Toggle the display of labels hidden in comments in the selection buffers.
> Sometimes, you may have commented out parts of your document. If these
> parts contain label definitions, RefTeX can still display and
> reference these labels.

For example, I loaded a test file, say [arabluatex.dtx](http://git.robertalessi.net/arabluatex/tree/arabluatex.dtx), moved point in the paragraph in `\section{Introduction}` (after line 465) and hit <kbd>C-c )</kbd>, when asked to `SELECT A REFERENCE FORMAT`, I hit <kbd>RET</kbd> followed by <kbd>SPACE</kbd>  for all labels.  In `*RefTeX Select*` buffer, I hit <kbd>%</kbd> and it looks like this:
[image]

I can now select a label as usual.

Comment: Thank you, this works.  Unfortunately, going through `C-c =` then hitting `l` leads to a dead end, but `C-c )` gives the expected result and saves me a lot of time.